# Manually/programmatically closes crosshair

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lightweight-charts

At the moment users have to tab/click on the graph to close the crosshair.

I'm trying to hide the crosshair when users released their thumb from screen (ontouchend). Is there a way to achieve that manually/programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope [this issue](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/438) is what you're looking for. This currently is not available though.

Comment: Yes it is, I must have overlooked. Will keep track the progress from there. Many thanks!